# Dropdown using IList needs Guid

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am having some trouble accessing a service that uses a Guid parameter to generate a .ToList()

```
 public IList<Info> GetBusinessLocations(Guid businessId)
    {
        using (var db = new DealerContext())
        {
            return GetDealerDetails(
                db.Details
                  .Join(db.BusinessLocations,
                  x => x.BusinessId,
                  y => y.BusinessId, (x, y) => x)
                  .Where(d => d.BusinessId == businessId), db)
                  .ToList();
        }
    }
```

I've tried writing an ActionResult with the guid as a parameter, but I continue to get an error that the  "parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'businessId' "

```
 public ActionResult Create(Guid businessId)
    {


        ViewBag.Locations = new SelectList(ServiceBus.GetBusinessLocations(businessId), "BusinessId", "LocationName");

        return View(IdGenerator());
    }


 private static Data.Models.Business IdGenerator()
    {
        var model = new Models.Business
        {
            BusinessId = Guid.NewGuid()
        };
        return (model);
    }
```

And in my view I simply call the dropdownlistfor

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m =>m.BusinessId, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Locations,"Select your Businesses Location")
```

If anyone could offer some insight I would greatly appreciate it.  I'm having a difficult time finding similar scenarios on SO.

Comment: Does your .Join generate any null Guids?  I'm thinking there may be a null returned to a non 1:1 mapped value.  If this may be the case, I may try to do a Nullable<Guid> that may solve the error you're getting?

Comment: I don't think that's the issue, there shouldn't be any nulls returned in the join.  Also when I use our WCF Test Client, I can manually enter in a Guid value for buisnessId, to return the data I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up changing this code a lot, so I'm closing this question with my fix.  Hopefully the method can help someone else.

Service Query

```
public IList<DealerInfo> GetBusinessLocations(Guid? locationId)
         {
        using (var db = new DealerContext())
             {
            var query = db.DealerDetails
                .Join(db.DealerValidations,
                    d=>new {bizId=d.BusinessId,lId=d.LocationId},
                    dv=>new {bizId=dv.BusinessID,lId= dv.LocationID},
                    (d,dv)=>d);

            if (locationId.HasValue)
                query = query.Where(d => d.LocationId == locationId.Value);

            return GetDealerDetails(query)
                .OrderBy(d =>d.DealerName)
                .ToList();
        }
    }
```

Controller Action

```
    public ActionResult GetLocations(Guid? id)
    {
        IList<DealerInfo> locations;

        locations = Service.GetBusinessLocations(id);


        ViewData["LocationId"] = new SelectList(locations, "LocationId", "DealerName", "(Select)");

        return PartialView("_DealerDropDown");
    }
```

Partial View

```
<div class="editor-field" id="locationdropdown">
    @Html.DropDownList("LocationId", ViewData["LocationId"] as SelectList, "(Select)", new { onchange = "onLocationSelected()", id="querydrop" })

</div>
```

I know this is very specific to my particular problem, but hopefully someone in a similar scenario may find this useful.